# php try catch wsod

Tags: php, try-catch, wsod

I have an issue. When I run:

```
try {
 $as
  ->setForename($_POST['fname'])
  ->setSurname($_POST['sname'])
  ->setEmail($_POST['email'])
  ->setUser($_POST['user'])
  ->setPass($_POST['pw'])
  ->setPhone($_POST['tel'])
  ->setMobile($_POST['mob'])
  ->setJob($_POST['job'])
  ->setAuth($_POST['auth'])
  ->addProcess();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
 echo $e;
}
```

I get "white screen of death" however when I use:

```
$as
 ->setForename($_POST['fname'])
 ->setSurname($_POST['sname'])
 ->setEmail($_POST['email'])
 ->setUser($_POST['user'])
 ->setPass($_POST['pw'])
 ->setPhone($_POST['tel'])
 ->setMobile($_POST['mob'])
 ->setJob($_POST['job'])
 ->setAuth($_POST['auth'])
 ->addProcess();
```

It all works fine. I am really confused please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try-catch` block seems to be fine, try putting these lines on top of your script to see the possible error:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: @sAc:

I have:

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_startup_errors",1);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

As an included header.

Comment: Its working again now, we havent changed any code! A weird one.

Comment: 'White screen of death's usually indicate a syntax error, so any `ini_set` & `error_reporing` method will NOT be executed. Set the values in `php.ini` or `.htaccess` and try again.

Comment: @Wrikken:

Setting any ini vars in .htaccess caused http 500 internal server errors in the past.

Comment: @Kyle Hudson: If it runs fine sometimes and not at other times then most surely it is not syntax error. It is some other issue, probably with server.

Comment: @sAc:

Quite possibly the server, should be migrating to a new one soon, will see if the error returns.

Thanks to everyone for their insight :D